# Dissecting the Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm trying to get a better handle on the Heine-Borel Theorem, but am finding different ways that it's framed. In Baby Rudin for instance:

> If a set in $R^k$ has one of the following properties, it has the other two:
>   (a) $E$ is closed and bounded
>   (b) $E$ is compact
>   (c) Every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$

However, the other formulations of the theorem that I've seen, simply use the closed/bounded implies compact formulation. Moreover, it's not entirely clear to me when each formulation holds. Rudin writes that (b) and (c) are equivalent in any metric space, but that (a) does not in general imply (b) and (c). I'm not sure what to make of that.

Can someone offer a way to bridge these formulations? When does one hold, but not the other? Is closed/bounded iff compact an appropriate formulation?

Comment: It will be more helpful if you ask a question :)

Comment: Ha, good point! Edited.

Comment: Yes. The point of Heine Borel is (a) implies (b) for $\Bbb{R}^k$. (i) For any metric space, rudin showed (b) implies (a) and (c). (ii) (c) implies (b) is left as exercise in ex. 26. An alternative approach is to prove Lebesgue number lemma while assuming (c). (iii) (a) does not imply (b) in general metric space if you take an infinite set and the discrete metric.

Comment: It is also useful to note that compactness is equivalent to completeness+totally boundedness. But you have do some reading to get to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple counterexample to the statement that closed and bounded implies compactness is the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where $d$ is the discrete metric. (ie $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$).

The subset $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in this metric and it is bounded because $d(x,y) \le 1$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. However $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact as it contains the sequence $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ which does not have a convergent subsequence.

Other interesting examples include the closed unit ball in an infinite dimensional normed vector space. And the metric space $((0,1),d)$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric.

As mentioned in comments if we have the stronger assumption that $(X,d)$ is complete and totally bounded (rather than just closed and bounded), then $(X,d)$ is compact.

Comment: This is very helpful. It seems that many of the online notes I've read in addition to Rudin are somewhat misleading as they tend to simply say that (a) implies (b).

Comment: (a) does imply (b) in a $\mathbb{R}^k$ with the Euclidean metric but yes it is misleading to not discuss how this result does not generalise to an arbitrary metric space.

Answer (score 0):

In any metric space we have $(c)\iff (b)$ and we have $(b)\implies (a).$